# SSRS multipul conditions in IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an IIF statement which looks something like

`IIF(Fields!Title.Value = "Option1", Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value) + 1),
IIF(Fields!Title.Value = "Option2", Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!st_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value) + 1),
IIF(Fields!Title.Value = "Option3", Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value) + 1)`

Is there a way to cut that down so I can have someting like

`IIF(Fields!Title.Valuie = "Option1" "Option2" "Option3", Fields!fbrt_OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!cce_TermEndDT.Value) + 1)`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

How about this [Switch](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ChrisAlbrektson/bidn-blog/1478/ssrs-switch-function-examples) ?

```
Switch(
Fields!Title.Valuie = "Option1",  
Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value)+1,

Fields!Title.Valuie = "Option2",
Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!st_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value)+1,

Fields!Title.Valuie = "Option3",
Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value)+1
)
```

OR

```
= IIF(Fields!Title.Value = "Option2", 
(Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!st_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value)+1),
(Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / (DateDiff("m", Fields!Effective_Date.Value, Fields!EndDT.Value)+1)
)
```

Comment: Even though SWITCH doesn't improve the character count much, it is the clearest logically.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Fields!OptionValue_Current.Value / 
         (DateDiff("m", 
                   IIF(Fields!Title.Value = "Option2",Fields!st_Date.Value, Fields!Effective_Date.Value),
                   Fields!EndDT.Value
                  )+1
         )
```

Comment: For clarity of other users that might have this problem, you should add some description about what you are doing. Thanks! :D

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MatthewR. This is a very specific situation, it is about how to rewrite the asker's code. But I will keep that in mind.